# How to create an entirely new page in react project

Tags: reactjs

Every time I search about this I get something related to react router and lazy loading. Isn't there a way to create an entirely separate page independent of index.js?
I created admin.js within my react project. If I go to `http://localhost:3000/admin`, it still loads index.js. I quite do not understand this bit of react if it is possible.

Comment: Depends on how the project has been set up and how it will be eventually deployed. On Nginx, for instance, you would set up an `url /admin { .. }` block to have precedence over the root, and it would serve a different page.

Comment: So this is a setup at server level.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible without router. And here is why: your `index.js` has nothing to do with what is loaded in the browser.

When navigating to `http://localhost:3000` your dev server actually serves a `index.html` to your browser. In it is a reference to a `bundle.js` (or however you name it) containing a bundled version of your `.js` files. So, `http://localhost:3000/admin` references to a `admin.html` which does of course not exist (unless you create it). But, doing this has several disadvantages over `react-router`. Because at build (or bundle) time `index.js` and `admin.js` will be two separate apps. Two separate `bundle.js`. Twice the amount of work needed to package it. Twice the amount of (maybe generated) `.html` files. Means no shared data at all. Twice the loading time in your browser. And many more.

I'd opt for `react-router` ;)

**Edit:** Of course it is not exactly twice in the points mentioned above. I am aware of that. But you get my point.

Comment: Unless the admin app really is entirely separate from the main app, e.g. the main app is user-facing and the admin app is only for superusers, in which case it might be a reasonable idea to separate them.

Comment: Maybe. But I'd rather separate it project wise then. Because it's likely being deployed into another network (admin-) zone requiring extra security.